# Possible to DELETE or UPDATE on junction table w/ no primary key

Tags: node.js, rest, typescript, sequelize.js, epilogue

I have a junction table called `PlanConflicts`, which allows for a many-to-many relationship between plans and conflicts.

Here is my model definition:

```
import { AllowNull, Column, DataType, ForeignKey, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";
import Conflict from "./Conflict";
import Plan from "./Plan";

@Table({ tableName: "PlanConflicts" })
export default class PlanConflict extends Model<PlanConflict> {
    @AllowNull(false)
    @ForeignKey(() => Plan)
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    public planId: number;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @ForeignKey(() => Conflict)
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    public conflictId: number;
}
```

Here is my attempt to generate endpoints for this table using epilogue:

```
epilogue.resource({
    model: PlanConflict,
    endpoints: ["/plan-conflicts", "/plan-conflicts/:id"],
    pagination: false,
    search: [
        {
            operator: "$eq",
            param: "plan-id",
            attributes: [ "planId" ]
        },
        {
            operator: "$eq",
            param: "conflict-id",
            attributes: [ "conflictId" ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I'm able to create a new conflict, and I can get a listing using a URL of the form `http://localhost:3000/plan-conflicts?plan-id=9&conflict-id=1`, but I can't figure out how I would perform an update or delete. The search feature of epilogue is only available for listings.

So, I'd like to know if it's possible to update or delete an item for a junction table that has no primary key, and if so, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours of rest, it dawned on me that I might just be able to just customize the endpoint from `.../:id` to `.../:planId/:conflictId` and sure enough, that did the trick.

My resource call is now simplified to:

```
epilogue.resource({
    model: PlanConflict,
    endpoints: ["/plan-conflicts", "/plan-conflicts/:planId/:conflictId"],
    pagination: false,
});
```

And here is an example URL: `http://localhost:3000/plan-conflicts/9/1`